# Call method when object is copied

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def normalize(self):
        self.value1 = 1
        return self
```

The objective of the `normalize` method is to ensure that whenever an "old" instance of MyClass is copied, the attribute `value1` is set back to `1`.

For instance:

```
myclassA = MyClass(15,25)
myclassB = myclassA.normalize()
print(myclassB.value1)
print(myclassB.value2)
>>1
>>25
```

This works. However, is there a way to achieve the same result without a separate method (`normalize()` in my case)? Can I make this happen automatically whenever an instance is created as a copy from another instance of the `MyClass` class?

Comment: Why do you want to copy the existing instance? Why not make a new one?

Comment: You're not actually making a "copy" here, you know that, right?

Comment: You haven't actually made any copies. `myclassA` and `myclassB` both refer to the same object, and if you check `myclassA.value1`, you'll see a value of `1`. Python isn't like C++, where implicit copies happen all over the place. Particularly, assignment, argument passing, and return values all operate without making copies. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: How are copies created? Do you mean with `copy.copy`? Python doesn't have the concept of "copy construction".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to do this using `__copy__`:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def __copy__(self):
        return self.__class__(1, self.value2)
```

then:

```
In [5]: from copy import copy                                                                                                                                                                  

In [6]: myclassA = MyClass(15,25) 

In [7]: myclassB = copy(myclassA)   

In [15]: myclassA.value1                                                                              
Out[15]: 15

In [16]: myclassB.value1                                                                                        
Out[16]: 1

In [17]: myclassA.value2                                                                                        
Out[17]: 25

In [18]: myclassB.value2                                                                                        
Out[18]: 25
```